# QGIS: Problem to rasterize track

Tags: qgis, gdal, line, rasterization

I'm not able to rasterize a GPS plot in QGIS (layer Chemins in red which is interpolation of GPS points) , the output is empty even though it works when I tried with a new simple layer with two line (two segments in black in the screenshot below).

[image]

I am using tool Vector to Raster in QGis like this:
[image]

But nothing in the output:
[image]

Comment: Check the output location using "Zoom to Layer".  If it stays the same screen, there is an issue. If it zooms to outside the current scene, then there may be a coordinate system discrepancy.

Comment: I would check the coordinate system and units. It looks like the data are in EPSG:4326 and the resolution is set to 5 degrees but I am not sure how the QGIS user interface sets the values.

Comment: True, it was a problem of coordinate system and units between a layer EPSG:4326 (GPS plot) and EPSG:2154 for the project. Thanks